# Get generated store Id in Ext.Net

Tags: ext.net

I have a Grid panel generated for the property model:

```
X.GridPanelFor(m => m.InvoiceItems, false, true, false)
```

True means that the Store is generated for this grid.

I cannot add a Store ID property for this grid because I get an error

```
X.GridPanelFor(m => m.InvoiceItems, false, true, false)
                            .StoreID("StoreName")
```

Error:

> Please do not set both the StoreID property on
>   GridPanelCust and  inner property at the same time.

I have tried pulling out the store ID from code like this:

```
App.GridPanelCust.getStore().getId()
```

But the error reported is that the

> getId() is not a function

Anyone know how can I pull out the Store ID from GridPanelFor generated one?

Comment: Try just App.GridPanelCust.getStore() and see if it finds the store.

Comment: It does find the store but the store does not have an ID property. I guess it's because it is auto generated

Comment: Strange, getId() would return an automatic generated id and not 'is not a function', try getStoreId()